# Visual Studio Team Services release XML transformation doesn't work

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Visual Studio Team Services - Build & Release

In the release definition, under File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options, there are XML transformation, and XML variable substitution.

I checked both checkboxes, but after deployment, nothing in my Web.Dev.config replaces web.config. The transformation doesn't happen at all.

What is the problem?

--------edit: detail---------

build

all the settings here is default.

[image]

release

[image]

web.dev.config

This transformation works fine if I deploy from visual studio 2015.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxxx;User ID=xxx@xxx;Password=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="NicoContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Nico.csdl|res://*/Nico.ssdl|res://*/Nico.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=xxxx;User Id=xxxx@xxxx;Password=xxxx;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="Dev" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <add key="AzureStorageContainerName" value="xxx" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="FacebookLoginAppId" value="xxx"   xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <add key="FacebookLoginAppSecret" value="xxx"   xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

[image]

--------edit 2: no longer work ---------

I did as the solution suggested on a new project in another Azure account, but this time it didn't work. For build, I choose template "Asp.net (preview)", for release, I choose template "Azure App Service Deployment".

[image]

[image]

--------edit 3: Release - Package or folder  ---------

[image]

Comment: What's task you used? Do you use Azure App Service Deploy task? What's the detail log? You can share detail log on the OneDrive.

Comment: What's the detail code of your web.config and web.dev.config?

Comment: Thanks, please check my edited post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already deployed/published the web app, so the web.config has already been transformed (For web package deployment, the related values in web.config will be updated during web deploy, the values are in **parameters.xml**).

So, there isn’t other config files (e..g web.dev.config, web.release.config) in published folder and check **XML transformation** and **XML variable substitution** is useless.

Based on the build log, the web app build with **release** configuration, but there isn’t **web.release.config**, so there isn’t update for web.config.

You can refer to these steps to achieve your requirement:

1. Publish/deploy the web app with **File System** way (e.g. /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl= $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\)
2. Add Copy file step copy others config files (web.dev.config, web.prod.config etc) to the published folder (artifact directory)
3. Add Publish Build Artifacts
4. For release, uncheck **Publish using Web Deploy** option and specify $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to **Package or folder**.

Comment: I have a new project and I do the same thing, but it no longer works...

Comment: @martial What's the detail build log? You may open a new thread include the detail build log and simple sample.

Comment: I edited the post, please check "edit 2: no longer work". I am wondering if you can make a Youtube video on how to make this work? :) I think many people would want to know...

Comment: @martial The reason is that the files not published to the artifact folder (Just 3 files published during publish artifact step). Try to add additional parameter: /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish. (/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish)

Comment: it doesn't work... There seems nothing happens on the Release step, since my website is not interrupted at all. See my edit, is it right there are only three config files under the drop folder?

Comment: @martial It is incorrect, the web app published files should be in the drop folder too. What's the detail build log after add /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish parameter? On the other hand, try to deploy the web app with FileSystem method through MSBuild tool and check whether the files are published to target folder.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I've tried several days and now have to give up. Instead I used Variables to deploy to different environments - although it takes extra efforts, it works.